# Excel 2013 - Nested IF(ISERROR(SEARCH not 'seeing' final statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm struggling to see why the below isn't working for the final statement:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Investment Commentary",E73)), IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Quarterly Update",E73)),"Quarterly Update"),"Investment Commentary")
```

So in Column `C` is my formula, and Column `E` contains text I'm searching.

My original formula has 12 of these and they all work, except for the last one.

I thought perhaps I'd hit a limit, but for some reason it refuses to see the final `IF` statement and simply returns `FALSE`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `IF` has a `TRUE` and `FALSE` part.....but the `TRUE` part consists of an `IF` statement with no `FALSE` part, so if the first `IF` is `TRUE` and the second is `FALSE` you get `FALSE`, you need to put something where I've indicated:

`=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Investment Commentary",E73)), IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Quarterly Update",E73)),"Quarterly Update","Something Here"),"Investment Commentary")`

Comment: Hi Barry, ah ok so I've tried that but I'm now getting '=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Investment Commentary",E73)), IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Quarterly Update",E73)),"Quarterly Update","Zero"),"Investment Commentary")'


The text I'm searching is 'Quarterly Update - Q1 2015' so I'd be expecting Quarterly Update to be returned, but I'm getting 'Zero'

Comment: OK, I assume you need to reverse those - when the IF is TRUE Quarterly Update isn't in the cell, so try `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Investment Commentary",E73)), IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Quarterly Update",E73)),"Zero","Quarterly Update"),"Investment Commentary")`